# Continuous growing of the ProGet packages

Tags: nuget-package, nuget-server, proget

We started using ProGet to host our packages. With our project still being in the early development phase we push packages often to our server. Our team is very distributed over the world so the pulling of packages to local computer is very important. We have noticed when we do a Nuget.exe -Update on a project and it pulls down the package from the server, it downloads the complete version xml list. On average that XML file is already between 300-550kb per package and growing by the day. Now we've been on ProGet for about 6 weeks, and with this growing in version XML file size it is going to be a real problem .

I have noticed that when we run the update that the "Microsoft*" packages all of them the "body length" in Fiddler is all around 461 bytes, and the body only contain one version.

Our package in the other hand the body in Fiddler contains all the versions from day one. Are we using ProGet wrong, or maybe a setting somewhere?

Comment: Could you add a link to a Fiddler trace showing a request of Microsoft packages vs. a local ProGet package?

Comment: As you will see from this screen dump the "Sage*" packages is our packages and all of them have the large body lengths

http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=7502a1a

Comment: Any news on this issue?